# Dom Parser Java - > 2 same name tag in different header with different Attributes. How?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

Im having a little problem with parsing the xml file using dom parser. Basically i want the xml listed below to be parsed by dom. The problem is that it gives me an error and to avoid it i want to read it properly. First of all i want it to read first, variables that are only in 1st header then after it read variables that are  only in 2nd header. I dont want to read it by item number cause not all 2nd header variables are same name as in 1st header so it will probably cause more problems. The whole xml is really big and i need to operate on about 50-60 variables in each header.

So somebody can give me any sample code or link how to read it using the header for it ??

```
<Analyzer version="2.0">
    <event1>
       <xxxx lll="FALSE" mmm="FALSE" ggg="FALSE" ccc="FALSE"/>
       <cccc lll="FALSE" mmm="FALSE" ggg="FALSE" ccc="FALSE"/>
    </event1>
    <event2>
       <xxxx drdr="2.500000000000000000000000e+00" zzzz="FALSE" />
       <notcccc drdr="1.556000000000000000000000e+00" zzzz="FALSE" />
    </event2>
</Analyzer>
```

Part of code of my program, i just didnt included the closing at the end.

```
File inputFile = new File("xxxx.xml");
             DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
             DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
             Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
             doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Analyzer"); 
             int k =0; 
             Node nNode = nList.item(k);
             Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("xxxx");
             nNode = nList.item(k); 
             eElement = (Element) nNode;
             System.out.println("Event :" + nNode.getNodeName());         
             class.lll = Boolean.valueOf(eElement.getAttribute("lll"));

nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("xxxx"); 
             nNode = nList.item(k); 
             eElement = (Element) nNode; 
             System.out.println("Event :" + nNode.getNodeName());
             class.xxxx2 = Float.valueOf(eElement.getAttribute("drdr"));
```

I am getting error listed below

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at configure.parseXml(configure.java:209)
    at configure.main(configure.java:28)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(Unknown Source)
    at configure.saveXml(configure.java:807)
    at configure.main(configure.java:29)
```

Comment: Ive just changed it a bit, i cant load whole xml file that got like 500+ lines and im not sure if i even can do it with parts . The names 1st / 2nd can be changed to like event1 / event2 for example if they are wrong. I just want the way to read it like i listed.

Comment: When you use the word “header,” are you referring to the child elements of AnalyzerConfiguration?  (The word “header” usually refers to a line of meta-information in a text-based protocol like HTTP or MIME.)

Comment: Yes it looks like, its not common for me to use xml's and thats why i lack some of words describing parts of it and i use the ones that fits best for me, im wrong as you can see.

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you include the code you have now to parse the XML?

Comment: I included part of the code after changing it a little bit. The error is listed too. I just dont know how to let parser know that i am looking only for variables inside the event1, then repeat the process for variables in event2. I think the problem is that the parser is getting 2 times the variable in event1.